# Add device to auto-generated Xcode 5 provisioning profile

Tags: xcode, provisioning-profile

I have created a simple project with XCode 5.
When I have created the project, XCode automatically generate the provisioning profile for my app. (I see it on my provisioning portal).
But now I added and removed some devices from my device list.
Is there a way to add a devices to provisioning profile generated by Xcode 5.

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Right click on the on your device and select "Add Device to Member Center". That will add your device to your provisioning portal.

[image: Example rightclick add device to member center]

Per XCode 5, provisioning profiles are managed by XCode 5. You see this in your Developer account.

[image: Screenshot provisioning center for developers @ apple]

If you wish to develop, you should create a new profile by clicking [+] on the top right and selecting "iOS App Development". You can then select which device you would like to add to this profile. Later on, you can add additional devices.

Apparently from Xcode, profiles that are managed by Xcode can not be altered.

[image: Screenshot add new development certificate]

Comment: This only works if you have physical access to the device. Is there a solution if you want  to allow someone hundreds of miles away to test your app?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out Asa? Having the same issue.

Comment: The best approach to this, is using tools like testflight. Those collect the device ID, which you can then import in your account and regenerate a provisioning profile. Once you've done that, you can distribute a build (adhoc) via Testflight to your users. Keep in mind that Apple only allows up to 100 unique devices to be added in your account at any time.

Comment: Except that you can't edit a profile that is being managed by Xcode from within the website. So the question still isn't answered. I have a UUID and I have imported that UUID to the account, how do I add it to a provisioning profile that is managed by Xcode 5?

Comment: You add a device for the UDID in the portal and refresh Xcode provisioning profiles. The Xcode managed provisioning profile will update to include the newly added device automatically (Xcode provisioning profiles include all devices you manage automatically). I haven't found a way in Xcode 5 to selectively include some devices but not others.

Comment: Still not working. I could not hate Apple anymore for making such an easy task so incredibly difficult.

Comment: Anybody know how to do this for xCode 6 as the right click menu no longer has this option?

Answer (score 15):

This is what worked for me:

Go to Apple development portal and add the device (UDID) as you normally do. Till now the UDID is not added to your provisioning profile.

In Xcode, go to project settings and select `Add an Account` from the `Team` dropdown.

[image]

A dialog will pop up. Just press `Cancel`. (if xCode automatically generated Profiles that means you'd already have the account setup. You don't need to add a new account)

Now from left side, select the Apple account this project belongs to.

Click `View Details`

Now just click the refresh button at the bottom left side of the window.

[image]

It will take some time to refresh, but when it finishes, the UDID will be added to your X-Code generated Provisioning Profile.

Comment: I am not sure though, how to limit the Provisioning Profile to include specific UDIDs only.

Comment: So the "refresh" button automatically adds any UUID that was recently added to the Members Center website? This does not appear to be working for me.

Comment: @pkamb it worked for me and it still does. If it doesn't work for you, you can try deleting all the `Provisioning Profiles` and `Certificates` from your member centre that belong to your app and let xCode manage everything. That usually works for me. xCode is finally taking charge of Member Centre. Which it should have taken from the beginning :-(

Comment: This worked for me too. Not at all intuitive but got the job done.

Comment: This worked for me in Xcode 6, but Apple removed that button for Xcode 7. :-(

Comment: Worked for me, after click on "Download All Profiles" button in same place. Xcode 8.2.1

Answer (score 2):

I deleted the provisioning profile from iOS Provisioning Profiles on developer.apple.com and then xCode automagically regenerated it with the new devices added.

Took a few "update please" in Preferences->Accounts->Provisioning Profiles in xCode before the change happened.