# xcode 5: How do you add a UUID to a provisioning profile managed by xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, uuid, provisioning-profile

As the title says, I am trying to add a device to a provisioning profile that is being managed by Xcode 5.

I added the UUID on the dev website, but I am unable edit the provisioning profile itself. Is there any way of adding the device other than creating a new provisioning profile that is not managed by xcode? Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Add device to auto-generated Xcode 5 provisioning profile](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19134000/add-device-to-auto-generated-xcode-5-provisioning-profile)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you have device that UUID you've tring to add 'in hand' ? If so go to your organizer, and click "use for development" button.

If you don't have that device, you have to create Distribution (AdHoc) provisioning profile, and add that UUID there.

Comment: This is an obnoxious solution for the case where you do not have the device in hand, but it appears the best we have for now. Thanks

Comment: Why obnoxious? If you don't have access to the device it means that you're distributing your app somewhere outside (for example for testers).

Weren't that Adhoc provisioning profiles made for?

Comment: The logic behind the ad hoc profiles makes sense, but it is a bit obnoxious that you can't manage all of your profiles from within xcode.