# How (what?) do I need to do to test my iPhone app on other iPhones?

Tags: ios, iphone, testing

So i've finally figured out how to get my app onto my iPhone, today. I can debug it also (woot) when the phone is connected to the cable.

Now, when i'm finished my tethered-testing ... how can i get my app onto a few other iPhones?

1. My wife: i physically have her phone, here at home.
2. My parents: don't have physical access to their phone.
3. Some friends: some i have physical access, some i do not.

What are my options?
How many phones can i put my app on (for testing)?
Is there an expiry time? 1 day? 1 week?

Comment: Have a look at this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40154/how-do-you-beta-test-an-iphone-app

Answer (score 1):

Each developer account can have 100 devices registered at a time, every year when you redo your membership apple asks if you want to clear out your devices. I assume it's also possible to delete devices from your dev account, I've never hit that limit. Any apps you install with the methods listed below will be usable until the provisioning profile expires (1 year). The provisioning profile is basically a custom script that allows non app store apps to be used on that specific phone, but apple caps the length those are valid to one year.

1) You can plug her phone into your computer and use it for development via Xcode's organizer like you did with your own phone

2) I recommend http://testflightapp.com/

3) Testflight again. Using testflight also allows you to release builds and your friends will get notified via email that a new version is available for download.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Before i check out this TestFlightApp thingy ... my app is made with Xamarin. Is that an issue?

Comment: I'm not familiar with it but it should not be an issue. All testflightapp requires is for you to be able to do a release mode build and upload the binary. So if you can submit to the app store using that software you can do testflight

Answer (score 1):

if you have a Apple Developer Account , then you can add  100 devices at a time for testing Purpose , Create  Development or Distribution Provisioning Profile   and  Add Device manually , to the perticular Provisioning that you have created

First add the device udid in devices list in devices list by clicking on '+' button on devices list Then after adding device udid then provisioning profile list then select required provisioning profile then you have a edit option their you want add new udid from devices list in bottom

[image]

After clicking edit button we have an option to select device udids

I hope this will help you Please use this link to Add the devices in your Provisioning Profile Link  [Click](https://developer.apple.com/account/ios/device/deviceList.action)

use the diawi.com to Create the wireless link of your application and simply download the application in your devices

Comment: Please use this link to add the devices if you are using xcode 5  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19134000/add-device-to-auto-generated-xcode-5-provisioning-profile