# After adding provisioning profile to Xcode, Xcode not responding

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ipad

Xcode was working fine, but after installing provisioning profile it hangs/ not responding  on start up(take 10-15 min).

I read this steps to solve, please let me know how can we do 1st step, I did all other (2nd and 3rd step).

If anyone have other solution please let me know. thank you.

```
1) deleted all Xcode related "Unsaved Docs" docs found via the Finder search;
2) removed the ~/Library/Developer folder;
3) Empty the trash.
```

Comment: have you add valid provisioning profile. First check it. if not then create Provisioning profile for your project from app store.

Comment: see this link and replay me  if you have any problem. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19134000/add-device-to-auto-generated-xcode-5-provisioning-profile

Comment: Thanks ashok, I added valid provisioning profile. Please let me know, how i can I do first step (deleted all Xcode related "Unsaved Docs" docs found via the Finder search;)

Comment: Check the if for any file there is M or A in front of that file. if yes then save it. clean the build and run it.

Comment: thanks @ Ashok, May you please, tell me in detail (how to deleted all Xcode related "Unsaved Docs")

Comment: no need to do that.  Go to window then organiser then click on project. Select your project and delete the derived data. Then exit Xcode. open again and clean build and then run again. please replay me after completion of this process.

Comment: Thank @ Ashok, working better than before now . you are genius.
please let me one more thing please, when I completely exit from xcode it take 10-15 min when I open project first time/at loading time. But when i just close project and run xcode again it takes 1-2 min, WHY ??
How can I solve this.???

Comment: may be it happens because of memory issue. you can expand your RAM so that this doesn't happen.

Comment: Thanks @ Ashok , But in my Mac there is enough memory , problem is another one . thanks

Comment: i am not talking about that memory. if you have 8 CPU Memory RAM(OR less) then it happens so don't.